¿Es posbile hacer un update de una tabla iceberg usando dataframes de pyspark?
soy nuevo en la ingeniería de datos y estoy teniendo problemas al entender como funcionan las tablas tipo iceberg y sus operaciones. Tal y como pone en:
https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/spark-writes/#update
Estas tablas admiten mediante sql la actualización de los datos en función de la condición que les pongas. Esto, a nivel de un valor concreto para una línea concreta tiene sentido, pero en mi caso, que estoy usando dataframes de pyspark no encuentro la forma de hacerlo más allá de hacer un join entre lo que quiero actualizar y la base de datos, unir las líneas que se cambian y finalmente sobrescribir la tabla entera.
El caso es, ¿hay alguna forma de hacer un update en una tabla de tipo iceberg en una base de datos utilizando un dataframe de pyspark con las líneas a actualizar como entrada?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
